# Spring MVC : java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response**

I am getting above error at return statement. In below two statements in method either one statement is working fine but not both.

```
public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
           ExcelUtils.downloadExcel(response.getOutputStream(), getExportData(command.getFile(), errors));
           return this.showForm(request, response, errors);
}
```

Here I am trying to download excel file and return to page to display message.
Can we can't call response.getOutputStream() and this.showForm(request, response, errors) or return new ModelAndView("redirect:/importPage.do") or return new ModelAndView("forward:/importPage.do") in single flow ?

Comment: what does the showForm method do ?

Comment: It will return ModelAndView org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem only the second time you export, try adding:

```
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Comment: After adding these two lines before return statement in my code , still getting same error.